# '+' symbol in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess. I try to pass a value in url like 'C++'.

like "**http://domain.com/Details/c++/detail.html**"

I am retrieving the value in htaccess like

RewriteRule ^Details/([a-zA-Z_0-9_.,'&/-]+)/(([a-zA-Z_0-9_.,'&/-]+).html)$  index.php?page=$2&id=$1

But it returns only 'c'. Symbol '+' not accepted. I need the the value 'c++'.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Where and how do you try to pass that value?

Comment: I have edited the question. i am retrieving the value $id

Comment: retagged, this is not a php question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Url encoding the `+` character.

"http://domain.com/Details/c%25%25/detail.html"

Comment: The problem is, that in a URL the `+` is the encoding for a space. You can circumvent this with g.'s method.

Comment: did I need to do this in .htaccess file?

Comment: `%20` is the encoding for a space.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to escape it, like `http://domain.com/Details/c%25%25/detail.html`. (I'm only guessing)

Answer (score 1):

`http://domain.com/Details/c%2B%2B/detail.html`

Answer (score 1):

A small consolation is: you are not alone. Since this problem is by design in URIs, eben big sites like Google have their problems with it:

http://www.google.com/search?q=c++

This does a search for just “c”.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the [*B* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

```
RewriteRule ^Details/([a-zA-Z0-9_.,'&/-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.,'&/-]+\.html)$ index.php?page=$2&id=$1 [B]
```